Why am I getting error on windows when I load model from ultralytics: AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'setsid'. Did you mean: 'getpid'?
I installed ultralytics using pip:
pip install ultralytics
I ran this code:
from ultralytics import YOLO
model = YOLO("yolo11n-pose.pt")
I am getting following error:
File "\computer_vision\Yoga_with_AI.venv\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\utils\downloads.py", line 297, in safe_run
preexec_fn=os.setsid,
^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'setsid'. Did you mean: 'getpid'?
I was expecting no errors. Could someone guide me how to fix this. (I do not want to change the downloaded source code in site-packages\ultralytics\utils\downloads.py)

FYI, the version 8.3.41 & 8.3.42 are infected with cryptominer. The line you are having trouble with is related to that. Link

I also had this problem with the latest version (8.3.41). Just install an earlier version : pip install ultralytics==8.3.40

Now since you mentioned it, I did receive a notification from windows that it has detected crpto miner program running because of this install. Also , when I tried to run this in Colab, my account is blocked due to this cryptominer program running. Shouldn't the ultralytics people have restricted access to their code repo. ? By the way, I did downgraded my package and it is working fine now.
